Install seaborn': The system cannot find the file specified
I was doing a machine learning model. Every thing was alright but when I tried to import seaborn it said seaborn was no defined. I was using python's virtual environment. So I activated my environment

..env\Scripts\Activate.ps1

Then I typed

pip install seaborn

But then it showed an error like this
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\mebub_9a7jdi8\Desktop\results\.env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\mebub_9a7jdi8\Desktop\Age_Gender_Detection_Model\.env\Scripts\pip.exe" install seaborn': The system cannot find the file specified.

I was expecting that the seaborn will installed and I can run my code
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(results,annot=True)

Now please tell me how can I install seaborn.

This question is similar to: Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is something wrong with your environment as it is calling Python from the .env directory in C:\Users\mebub_9a7jdi8\Desktop\results, but trying to execute pip from  the one in C:\Users\mebub_9a7jdi8\Desktop\Age_Gender_Detection_Model. If your setup is correct then both paths should be the same.

I have solved the installation error for seaborn. For that I only had to re create the virtual environment. Then I successfully installed the seaborn.
